# NVIDIA GPUs and PhysX engine

Tags: gpu, gpgpu, nvidia, physx

How is the NVIDIA PhysX engine implemented in the NVIDIA GPUs: It's a co-processor or the physical algorithms are implemented as fragment programs to be executed in the GPU pipeline ?

Comment: I believe it's layered on top of the fragment programs. However isn't this a question for `SuperUser` ??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PhysX is implemented using NVIDIA's CUDA (GPGPU implementation). There isn't a separate co-processor or other dedicated piece of silicon.